# A new diagram always appears after each button click

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently programming a GUI in which a diagram with data from a CSV file should be displayed. Since new data is always being added to the CSV, I want to display a current history after each button click.

My problem: After every button click, a new diagram appears instead of a new course in the old diagram (see image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aGew.png)

My Code for the Graph:

```
def graph():

# List 1
liste_1_x = ["06:15", "15:30"]
liste_1_y = [0,16000]

# List 2
list_2_x = []
list_2_y = []

#--------------------------------------------------

import csv

with open("testdata.csv", "r") as filedata:
    lines = csv.reader(filedata, delimiter=",")
    for row in lines:
    list_2_x.append(row[0])
    list_2_y.append(int(row[1]))

#--------------------------------------------------

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)


fig = Figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)

plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)        
plot1.plot(liste_1_x,liste_1_y, color="b", marker="o")
plot1.plot(list_2_x, list_2_y, color="r", marker="o")
plot1.grid()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=tkFenster)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)


toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, tkFenster)
toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, expand = 1)
```

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

# Create the figure and canvas outside of the function
fig = Figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=tkFenster)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, tkFenster)
toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, expand = 1)

# Keep a reference to the plots outside of the function
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = plot1.plot([], [], color="b", marker="o")
line2, = plot1.plot([], [], color="r", marker="o")
plot1.grid()

def graph():
    # List 1
    liste_1_x = ["06:15", "15:30"]
    liste_1_y = [0,16000]

    # List 2
    list_2_x = []
    list_2_y = []

    # Read data from CSV
    with open("testdata.csv", "r") as filedata:
        lines = csv.reader(filedata, delimiter=",")
        for row in lines:
            list_2_x.append(row[0])
            list_2_y.append(int(row[1]))

    # Update the data in the existing plots
    line1.set_xdata(liste_1_x)
    line1.set_ydata(liste_1_y)
    line2.set_xdata(list_2_x)
    line2.set_ydata(list_2_y)

    # Redraw the canvas to reflect the changes
    canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Hi SuperStew, thank you in advance for your help, it has helped me.                                             The values ​​for the liste_1_x are times that are entered in a GUI (HH:MM) like this:                                                                                                                                       'liste_1_x = [ str(entry_produktionsbeginn.get()), str(entry_end.get()]'                                 ***Now I get the error message***: matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['06:15', '17:36']

Comment: Is there a way to use matplotlib.animation to solve the problem?